# Story where a member of the MC's party takes a holy item from the grave of a cursed priestess

Tags: story-identification, novel, manga

I know there's a novel, but it could also be a webtoon/manhwa/manhua.

The MC and his group head to an area with a curse to scout it out and fight some strong beasts. Then they head to cave where the MC somehow figures it out and they head in, but a member of a group stupidly takes a holy item from a grave even after warnings, and the MC fixes the situation by taking the holy item and giving it back.

The MC also goes back for the priestess and they travel together. I remember a mansion with a bunch of cursed spirts and her uncle there. She was also part of a very rich family that the emperor killed, but they hid their treasure and the MC and her travel around and get it.

Comment: Welcome Cake. Please take our [tour] and read the [help]. You might also take a look at our [story ID checklist](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and see if you can add some details - the year it was written, the language it was in etc..

Comment: @Cake - Looks like someone attempted to edit your question using a different account. If that was you, I gather that means you've lost access to your first account, and can't directly edit this question yourself anymore. You can solve this problem by following the instructions provided [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to merge your new account with the old one. We'd appreciate it if you'd do that, as it'd also allow you to leave comments beneath this question, and to mark a correct answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).